# Log every invocation of every SUID program?

Tags: linux, security, logs

I would like to have a log file that contains an entry for every time a user runs any suid program, containing the user name, the program and any command line arguments passed to it. Is there a standard way to achieve this on Linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can log all invocations of a specific executable (setuid or not) through the [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/). The documentation is rather sparse; start with the [auditctl man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/auditctl.8.html), or perhaps [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html). Most recent distributions ship an `auditd` package. Install it and make sure the `auditd` daemon is running, then do

```
auditctl -A exit,always -F path=/path/to/executable -S execve
```

and watch the calls get logged in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` (or wherever your distribution has set this up).

Comment: I guess one could write a script to first get all SUID binaries with find and then use your solution for each one. Not elegant, but certainly doable. Thanks!

Comment: @Kim: I think you can log all invocations of a setuid root binary by a not-root user by replacing `-F path=…` with `-F euid=0 -F 'uid!=0'` or something like it. I can't see a hook in [the setxid code invoked by `execve`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/fs/exec.c#L1219) nor a specific setxid watch in the [audit subsystem](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/kernel/auditsc.c). Or, of course, you can log every `execve` and postprocess.

Comment: Interesting. Never heard of this before. I wonder how widely used it is. Debian popcon doesn't have an entry for `auditd`.

Comment: `find` command to list all the SUID files: `find / -xdev \( -perm -4000 \) -type f -print`

Comment: @FaheemMitha It has an popcon entry: http://qa.debian.org/popcon-graph.php?packages=auditd

Comment: I am getting `WARNING - 32/64 bit syscall mismatch, you should specify an arch`.  How do I specify the arch?

Comment: Add `-F arch=b64` to the command.