# Which processes should I NOT strace?

Tags: process, strace

I've created a little function for `strace`'ing a set of the current user's processes by name:

```
function pstrace() {
    local pattern="$1";
    shift;
    prefixDashP $(pgrep -U $(whoami) $pattern) | xargs strace -o /dev/stdout $@;
}

function prefixDashP() {
    local new_args=();
    for arg; do
        new_args+=( '-p' );
        new_args+=( "$arg" );
    done;
    for arg in "${new_args[@]}"; do
        echo "$arg";
    done;
}

# Usage:  pstrace pattern1 pattern2 ...
```

The trouble is, if I accidentally specify too broad of a pattern, it tries to monitor processes that it shouldn't monitor, and so my system freezes.

Is there a list of processes that I can always exclude?

Answer (score 6):

You must not trace any process that's involved in processing the output of `strace`. This means, at least, the terminal emulator in which you're running strace. I wouldn't expect your whole system to be frozen, only slowed down; uless you're running `strace` as root and tracing your X server, you should be able to switch to a different terminal and kill the strace process.

It would be less risky and probably more convenient to send the strace output to a file. Start `less` after starting `strace`, and kill it if you've accidentally traced the terminal emulator.

If you feel like tracing a lot of processes, you may be using the wrong tool. A system-wide audit system, such as Linux's (see examples and pointers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13017/log-every-invocation-of-every-suid-program/13024#13024) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13776/determine-which-process-is-creating-a-file/13791#13791)), may be more appropriate.

Comment: Well spotted! Looks more like a livelock than a deadlock, so the system will probably be unstable (at least).